# Cannot map LINQ to Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda, dto

I'm not very clear with writing linq queries. I write a query to select only certain columns from a table using linq lambda expression and I get the error that linq cannot be constructed to entities. The same query when I write using linq to select all columns I don't get any errors and I get all the columns, which i later filter out in the view. But I want to use the lambda to select only certain columns.

Code snippet:

ViewModel:

```
public class StaggingInternalCashExceptionViewModel
    {



        public OutputCash OutputCash { get; set; } 
        public IEnumerable<StaggingInternalException> StaggingInternalException { get; set; }
        //list of results of Stagginginternalcashexception
    }
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Exceptionstest(string dd1, string dd2, string dd3)
{
     StaggingInternalExceptionViewModel _app = new StaggingInternalExceptionViewModel();

_app.StaggingInternalException = db2.StaggingInternalExceptions.Where(x => x.Level1 == dd1 && x.Level2 == dd2 ).Select(i => new StaggingInternalException
         {


             StaggingInternalRowID = i.StaggingInternalRowID,
             Category = i.Category,
             EnterText1 = i.EnterText1,
             InternalAmount = i.InternalAmount,
             ExternalAmount = i.ExternalAmount

         });

  _app.StaggingInternalException = (from p in db2.StaggingInternalExceptions 
                                                 where p.LoadID==loadid && p.Level1 == dd1 && p.Level2 == dd2   select p);
}
```

In the above code, the lambda expression throws an error when I'm trying to select only certain columns from the table or if we are speaking in terms of entity classes, only certain properties. But the query returns all the columns. Should I be using DTOS? I'm not sure what the use of data transfer objects is. Some explanation on this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a DTO.
A dto is just an object that you map your result to. In your case it would be

```
public class StaggingInternalExceptionViewModel
{
     public int StaggingInternalRowID { get; set; }
     public int Category { get; set; }
     ... //rest of properties
}
```

You need to change your StaggingInternalCashExceptionViewModel to use the StaggingInternalException DTO

```
public class StaggingInternalCashExceptionViewModel
{
    public OutputCash OutputCash { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<StaggingInternalExceptionViewModel> StaggingInternalException { get; set; }
    //list of results of Stagginginternalcashexception
}
```

Then your expression stays the basically the same but you select a new StaggingInternalExceptionViewModel instead of StaggingInternalException

```
StaggingInternalExceptionViewModel _app = new StaggingInternalCashExceptionViewModel();

_app.StaggingInternalException = db2.StaggingInternalExceptions.Where(x => x.Level1 == dd1 && x.Level2 == dd2 ).Select(i => new StaggingInternalExceptionViewModel
     {
         StaggingInternalRowID = i.StaggingInternalRowID,
         Category = i.Category,
         EnterText1 = i.EnterText1,
         InternalAmount = i.InternalAmount,
         ExternalAmount = i.ExternalAmount
     });
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I kinda got an idea, going to try it out.My view model has an IEnumerable<StaggingInternalException>. So can I create an object of that viewmodel and map it. As in something like app.StaggingInternlaCashException=the query. Would that be right?

Comment: You need to create a StaggingInternalExceptionViewModel and then use Select on the query just like in the answer, the only difference is that in the answer it's called StaggingInternalExceptionDTO instead of StaggingInternalExceptionViewModel

Comment: Shouldn't it be IEnumerable<StaggingInternalExceptionDTO> StaggingInternalExceptionDTO. I want a list of StaggingInternalException class.
public IEnumerable<StaggingInternalExceptionDTO> StaggingInternalException { get; set; }

Comment: add .ToList(), after the select ...ExternalAmount = i.ExternalAmount }).ToList(), if you don't call .ToList() it doesn't actually make the request to the database hence the IQueryable type

Answer (score 1):

Linq to Entities doesn't let you project a query using an entity type because you can end up losing information at loading an entity partially and trying later to save that entity to your DB. So, you must project your queries when you need partial information of an entity whether using a [DTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) or an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

If you need to use the entity type, then don't project using `Select` method, the only thing is you're going to load  all the properties, but I think this is not the case because you don't need all the data ;).

Comment: I cannot use an anonymous type here because i get the error that it cannot implicity convert generic anonymous type to generic IEnumerbable<StaggingInternalCashExceptions> type. So i think only DTOs work here?

Comment: yes, you need an strong type, so, define a class with the properties you need and project over it, and change the return type of your method, eg;`IEnumerbable<StaggingInternalCashExceptionDTO>`

Comment: I just edited my question. I added the viewmodel, how do i do _app.StaggingInternalException= db2.StaggingInternalExceptions.Where(x => x.Level1 == dd1 && x.Level2 == dd2 ).Select(i => new StaggingInternalExceptionDTO
            {
                StaggingInternalRowID = i.StaggingInternalRowID}).  The error i get is cannot implicity convert type IQueryable to IEnumerable. But i thought it returns the result in IEnumerable by default.